# How to expand a list property for each item in an msbuild `ItemGroup`?

Tags: msbuild

How to expand a list property for each item in an `ItemGroup`? If I tried the following then the property get expanded for all items:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Foo Include="foo">
        <Bar>a;b;c</Bar>
    </Foo>    
    <Foo Include="bar">
        <Bar>d;e;f</Bar>
    </Foo>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Foobars Include="%(Foo.Bar)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="%(Foo.Identity) %(Foo.Bar) @(Foobars -> '%(Identity)', ' ')" />
</Target>
```

The output is:

```
foo a;b;c a b c d e f
bar d;e;f a b c d e f
```

What I need is:

```
foo a;b;c a b c
bar d;e;f d e f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the original `%(Foo.Identity)` and `%(Foo.Bar)` as metadata to `Foobars` items, you can restrict the values that `@(Foobars)` includes when iterating over the metadata values:

```
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Foo Include="foo">
            <Bar>a;b;c</Bar>
        </Foo>    
        <Foo Include="bar">
            <Bar>d;e;f</Bar>
        </Foo>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <Foobars Include="%(Foo.Bar)">
              <Foo>%(Foo.Identity)</Foo>
              <Bar>%(Foo.Bar)</Bar>
            </Foobars>
        </ItemGroup>

        <Message Text="%(Foobars.Foo) %(Foobars.Bar) @(Foobars -> '%(Identity)', ' ')" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

produces:

```
$ dotnet msbuild
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.234.47922 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  foo a;b;c a b c
  bar d;e;f d e f
```